# How to do :document.getElementById() in extjs syntax

Tags: extjs

In jsp, if there is a hidden variable, we do this in js:

```
document.getElementById('hiddenVarId').setValue = 'xxx';
```

What is the extjs equivalent of `document.getElementById().setValue = 'xxx';`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Ext.get('hiddenVarId').set({value: 'xxx'});
```

This another possibility that leverages the ExtJS method `set()`. This way you can set multiple attributes on an Ext.Element at once if that's something you also require now or later.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Element

Answer (score 8):

```
Ext.get('hiddenVarId').dom.value = 'xxx';
```

[Ext.get](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.html#method-Ext-get) returns an `Ext.Element` which has the actual DOM object in the `dom` property. You can then directly assign to the `value` property.

Answer (score 3):

```
Ext.getCmp('hiddenVarId').setValue('xxx');
```

Ext.get() vs Ext.getCmp()

Comment: What are differents ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166017/can-you-please-explain-el-getel-ext-get-in-detail