# Can you please explain .el, getEl(), Ext.get() in detail?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am new to Sencha ExtJs

I did not understand the line `Ext.getCmp('component_id').getEl().hide();`. what is the use of `.getEl()`. Can i write `Ext.getCmp('component_id').hide();` directly?

And explain me about .el, `Ext.get()` also.

Answer (score 14):

## Ext.getCmp() VS Ext.get()

`Ext.getCmp()` finds an existing (created) **component** in ExtJS component tree. Note that it is *discouraged* to use it. Rely on [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) instead.

`Ext.get()` finds a **DOM element** by id. For example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="target">Hello, world!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`Ext.get('target')` will return `div#target` DOM element.

I personally never use either one. Instead, I locate components using ComponentQuery and then retrieve their DOM elements, as described below.

## MyCmp.getEl() VS MyCmp.el

Both just retrieve the top level DOM element of the MyCmp component.

Current version of ExtJS (4.2.1) defines the `.getEl()` function as follows:

```
MyCmp.getEl = function () {
    return this.el;
}
```

Which means that `MyCmp.getEl()` and `MyCmp.el` are **absolutely equal**.

Use `.el` if you prefer to keep your code short and sweet. However, `.getEl()` might be useful in case if in the future ExtJS adds additional logic to the component's DOM element retrieval process (e.g. checking whether it exists or not first).

I prefer `.el`.

## MyCmp.hide() VS MyCmp.el.hide()

`MyCmp.hide()` and `MyCmp.el.hide()` are two different functions. Current version of ExtJS (4.2.1) defines them as follows:

```
MyCmp.hide = function (animateTarget, cb, scope) {
    var me = this,
        continueHide;
    if (me.pendingShow) {
        delete me.pendingShow;
    } if (!(me.rendered && !me.isVisible())) {
        continueHide = (me.fireEvent('beforehide', me) !== false);
        if (me.hierarchicallyHidden || continueHide) {
            me.hidden = true;
            me.getHierarchyState().hidden = true;
            if (me.rendered) {
                me.onHide.apply(me, arguments);
            }
        }
    }
    return me;
}
```

and

```
MyCmp.el.hide = function (animate){
    if (typeof animate == 'string'){
        this.setVisible(false, animate);
        return this;
    }
    this.setVisible(false, this.anim(animate));
    return this;
}
```

However, both functions seem to produce **identical results**. They just add a `style="display: none;"` to the component's DOM element.

I use `MyCmp.hide()`.

Comment: haha I thought that el was maybe because they had some spanish developers or something.  Kindof like the var that = this thing.  It's actually to do with the dom element instead?

Comment: hahaha .el - that's funny! As to your question: there are 3 different objects. An **Ext.Component**, an **Ext.Element**, and a plain **DOM element**. They relate to each other like this: `cmp.el.dom`. So Ext.Element encapsulates the DOM element, and the Ext.Component in turn encapsulates the Ext.Element.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) `Ext.getCmp('')`  -> ExtJS maintains component list when page is constructed. Using getCmp('unique ID') fetches component from the list
>
> 2) `getEl()`         -> returns HTML element / DOM of the component
>
> 3) `hide()`          -> just applies css (e.g.: `"display:none"`) to the style of the component

### So

`Ext.getCmp('component_id').hide()`

is equivalent to

`Ext.getCmp('component_id').getEl().hide()`

Comment: `Component` has a [`hide()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-hide) method.

Comment: I am sorry its long time since i refered the docs. let me edit

Comment: "Ext.getCmp('component_id').hide() is same as using Ext.getCmp('component_id').getEl().hide()" Not correct at all.