# Unable to get el element for Ext.Component

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs

```
GraphReportPanel = function (config, initData) {
GraphReportPanel.instance = this;


this.graphPanel = new Ext.Container({
    id : 'graphPanelId'
});

GraphReportPanel.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
    title : 'Graph',
    autoScroll: true,
    id : 'graphReportPanel',
    items: [this.graphPanel],
    collapsible : false
});

};
```

I have created GraphReportPanel . Now when i use the following code

```
Ext.getCmp('graphPanelId').el.dom.innerHTML = '';
```

I get `Ext.getCmp('graphPanelId').el` as undefined . Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getEl()` returns the dom element only if your component is rendered. Please check if the component is rendered before you call this method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the component was not rendered . But when does rendering happen for a component in extjs . I am new to javascript , so I don't understand it.

Comment: You have put the graphPanel container as an item of the `GraphReportPanel`. I don't know to which component you are appending the GraphReportPanel, to some other component or the document body. `renderTo: Ext.get('my-div-name')` or `renderTo: Ext.getBody()`  will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ext.getCmp('graphPanelId').getEl()` instead of `Ext.getCmp('graphPanelId').el`.

More information in this topic : [Can you please explain .el, getEl(), Ext.get() in detail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166017/can-you-please-explain-el-getel-ext-get-in-detail)

Comment: thank you .. but I think the actual cause was that the component was not rendered. So `Ext.getCmp('graphPanelId').getEl()` didn't help.